Custom Serilog operator
I'm looking for a way to add a custom operator (as defined here) within the message template. Specifically, I would like to add another operator * that should be treated as an object value (same as @). The reason for this, is to be able to detect these properties for post processing. For example, using an Enricher to automatically add extra properties given a * property is present.
Is there a way to do this at the moment (I couldn't find any)? Are there plans to support additional operators in the future?
